# Desktop application login using count

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc

I am trying to call a page when a user validates as "Admin" or "User" but there seems to be a problem.

```
private void validateLogin() {
    if (getFieldData() == true) {
        username = txtname.getText();
        String password = new String(txtpassword.getPassword());
        Object type = cbType.getSelectedItem();
        //validate login and password here. 
        //validity will be done by sending login/password to the database
        String sql = "select  count(*) from usermanagement where UserName='" 
                + username + "' and " + "Password='" + password + "'";
        ResultSet rs = datacon.queryTable(sql);
        try {
            rs.next();
            if (rs.getInt(1) > 0) {
                if (type.equals("Admin")) {
                    MainMenu mainmenu = new MainMenu();
                    this.dispose();
                    mainmenu.setVisible(true);
                } else {
                    UserMenu usermenu = new UserMenu();
                    this.dispose();
                    usermenu.setVisible(true);
                }
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, 
                        "Incorrect username or password or user category", 
                        "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                clearField();
                txtname.requestFocusInWindow();
                cbType.setSelectedIndex(0);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem ??

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Please use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.  3) *"here seems to be a problem.."*  What problem?

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: thnks andrew New Idiot and Anshulkatta --> after i have entered the validations according to my databasei.e User Category "Admin"or "User" Username "timo" and Password "timo123" its not calling the next page which is either Mainmenu or Usermenu,,,myt it be wrong declaration on 'rs.next()' and 'if(rs.getInt(1)>0)'

Comment: can you add exception report?

Comment: @reggea post sop in the blocks if and else and check if its going in those blocks or not

Comment: [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice)

Comment: zapateus its there "ex.printStackTrace();" but all its bringing is an error am new to java and trying to devlop a simole app..

Comment: @anshulkatta hehehe i havent understood what u mean by "post sop in the blocks" am still learning java and from my back end db the connection is gud....MAdProgrammer let me check it out thnks

Comment: @reggea System.out.println("print something") , put it in if and else , and check if it is going in those blocks , may be they are not going in those blocks instead !!

Comment: @reggea moreover , i see that you are not checking the user from the results from database , u r just getting the records number , if its greater than 0 then check for admin , this is totally not good approach  :)

Comment: *"after i have entered the validations according to my database"*  This is relevant information that should be [edited into the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17059060/edit).  Use code formatting where appropriate.

Comment: @andrew am trying to put all the codes but its giving an error,,,@anshulkatta when am using rs.getInt(1)>0 it checks in the database whether a user has any Idno matching the userdetails wat dyu suggest...?

Comment: *"am trying to put all the codes"*  Why?  I recommended you post an SSCCE. *"but its giving an error"*  ..what is the error?  Pretend for a moment I am neither psychic nor sitting behind you, looking over your shoulder.

Comment: @Andrew i have posted the codes its saying excess codes inset i have tried the SSCCE guide,sory..

Comment: *"excess codes"*  I managed to fit over 600 lines of code into the Q&A on the [File Browser GUI](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/file-browser-gui).  Given that 600 LOC is too long to be called an 'S'SCCE, I can only conclude that what you tried to post is ..not an SSCCE.  In any case, good luck with it..

Answer (score 0):

I am not seeing the your inputs here, username and password. It would be best to attach your logs to get a glimpse of what the Exception states about your problem.

From what I see in code here are my suggestions,

- You should refrain from using  this `UserName='"+username +"'`   on your sqls, this is appalling for special Charaters can break your sql. I suggest you adhere to something like PreparedStatement  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html
- It's better to adhere `if(rs.next())` to check if record exists. it's not safe to access `rs.getInt(1)` , If you're not having any matching records, it can break your application.

Comment: thnks @Macon, when it brings that error the username tab gives the number the user is in the database eg timo is number 3... i have my users with each having an Id...that is why am using the rs.getInt(1) letme try what u have suggested on UserName='"+username +"'..

Comment: @reggea I suggest you use something like  
                if(rs.next() && (rs.getInt(1)>0))

Comment: @Macon ts still giving th same error,,thnks bdw instead of using UserName='"+username +"'what dyu suggest i use,,to reference the username textbox

Comment: @reggea  Pls share the Exception stacktrace

Comment: @Macon what it is really bringing is "Incorrect username or password or user category","Error" as error,its neither giving any Exceptions of which i have specified it,,,think this "if(rs.getInt(1)>0)" is what is bringing an error to call the MainMenu or UserMenu

Comment: @reggea change your '"if(rs.getInt(1)>0)"'

to 'if(rs.next() && (rs.getInt(1)>0))'

Comment: @reggea Have you removed the standalone line rs.next() ?